# Kernel Device Driver "dereferencing 'void *' pointer

Tags: c, pointers, kernel, driver, void-pointers

I am learning how to write device drivers for linux, and I have a question regarding the use of generic data structures.

I have an assignment, which I have fully functional...so I'm not asking you to do my homework...

This assignment requires a device to be able to enqueue and dequeue elements from a fifo buffer. I made the buffer "generic" so that any element size could be used(and specified at runtime). The source is included below(note this is not the kernel version, but the error is the same)...kernel version requires kmalloc, copy_to/from_user() etc...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct RB_Buffer
{
    void* RBData;
    unsigned int getindex;  //index to remove element
    unsigned int putindex;  //index to put element at
    unsigned int capacity;  //max elements buffer holds
    unsigned int elemCount; //num elements inserted
    unsigned int elemSize;  //size of each element
};

void* RB_kcreate(int numElements, unsigned int elementSize);
int putring(struct RB_Buffer *rbptr, void* data);
int getring(struct RB_Buffer *rbptr, void* data);


//Creates a Ring buffer of specified number of elements and element size.
//Returns void* pointer pointing to the RB_Buffer struct. This pointer can
//then be used on putring and getring functions.
void* RB_kcreate(int numElements, unsigned int elementSize)
{
    struct RB_Buffer *newBuf = malloc(sizeof(struct RB_Buffer));
    if(newBuf == NULL) return 0;
    newBuf->RBData = (void*)malloc(elementSize*numElements);//, GFP_KERNEL);
    if(newBuf->RBData == NULL)
    {
        free(newBuf);
        return 0;
    }
    newBuf->capacity = numElements;
    newBuf->elemSize = elementSize;
        newBuf->getindex = 0;
        newBuf->putindex = 0;
        newBuf->elemCount = 0;

    return newBuf;
}

//puts an element in the buffer. Returns -1 if full, 0 on success
//send data through void* data argument
int putring(struct RB_Buffer *rbptr, void* data)
{
    int i = 0;
    if ( rbptr->elemCount >= rbptr->capacity )
        return -1;

    memcpy(&rbptr->RBData[rbptr->putindex * rbptr->elemSize], data, rbptr->elemSize);
    rbptr->putindex++;
    if (rbptr->putindex >= rbptr->capacity )
        rbptr->putindex = 0;
    rbptr->elemCount++;

    return 0;
}

//removes an element in the buffer. Returns -1 if empty, 0 on success
//data is returned through the data pointer
int getring(struct RB_Buffer *rbptr, void *data)
{
    if ( !rbptr->elemCount )
        return -1;


    rbptr->elemCount--;
    memcpy(data, &rbptr->RBData[rbptr->getindex * rbptr->elemSize], rbptr->elemSize);
    rbptr->getindex++;
    if ( rbptr->getindex >= rbptr->capacity )
        rbptr->getindex = 0;

    return 0;

}
```

When I compile this into a kernel module, I get the warnings:

`kringbuf_generic.c:53: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer
kringbuf_generic.c:72: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer`

The error occurs here in putring(in memcpy)

```
if ( rbptr->elemCount >= rbptr->capacity )
            return -1;

        memcpy(&rbptr->RBData[rbptr->putindex * rbptr->elemSize], data, rbptr->elemSize);
        rbptr->putindex++;
```

and here in getring, in the memcpy() function

```
rbptr->elemCount--;
        memcpy(data, &rbptr->RBData[rbptr->getindex * rbptr->elemSize], rbptr->elemSize);
        rbptr->getindex++;
```

Obviously since this is a kernel module, it is not really known who will use this, and the fixing the buffer element size would limit the usage of this buffer.

Is there any way to get rid of the warnings? Or is there some fundamental thing I should be doing differently when developing such code?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to count the lines to figure out which is line 72. But can't you eliminate the warning with a typecast?

Comment: Would be nice if you told us WHERE the error is happening. I suppose it's the copy_to_user line? What's the second argument for copy_to_user?

Comment: sorry lol, fixed. changed the code to a version anyone can use(non kernel).

Comment: Sorry, new to stack overflow...wasn't intuitive how to accept answer...

Comment: humm, a big tick which has a tooltip if one hovers the mouse over it... sorry, im not having a dig, welcome and have fun...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that this code:

```
rbptr->RBData[rbptr->getindex * rbptr->elemSize]
```

Is trying to index into the array pointed at by `RBData`, which is of type `void *`.  You can't meaningfully make this operation work on a `void*` pointer, because indexing into an array in C requires you to know the size of the elements in the array, and by definition a `void*` is an a pointer to elements of an unknown type.

Most compilers let you do this anyway by implicitly casting the `void*` to a `char*` and just reading raw byte values.  However, it's really not a good idea to do this, since the operation isn't well-defined.

To fix this and silence the warning, consider explicitly typecasting the `RBData` field to a `char*` before dereferencing it:

```
((char *)rbptr->RBData)[rbptr->getindex * rbptr->elemSize]
```

Or alternatively, just store it as a `char*` in your struct to avoid having to repeatedly do this typecast.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! That really helps. No more warnings!